# Confirming (computationally) an integral with polar coordinates.

Tags: integration, trigonometry, polar-coordinates, computational-mathematics

The following integral has been proposed:

$$
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sqrt[8]{x^{2}+\ln ^{2} \cos x} \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\ln ^{2} \cos x}{x^{2}+\ln ^{2} \cos x}}}} d x=\frac{\pi}{2} \sqrt[4]{\ln 2}
$$

I approximated the behavior of the LHS by summing consecutive terms (everything after the integral sign) by increasing x. This was done in Javascript.

**Running x to large values** shows the LHS as divergent:

[image]

...while the RHS is equal to exactly `1.307`.

Presumably, at some early point, the LHS should equal the RHS. Is it feasible to discover where this is using my approach? Summation is increasing x by units of 1, which in a sense is course-graining what would otherwise be done using proper integration. But should I expect to see the “convergence” (overlap?) somewhere early in my summation?

Obviously I would need to inspect the “series” (calling it series since this is how I’m treating it) between the values of 0 and π/2. But Since I am increasing x in the regular number line I need to convert the polar coordinates to reals (I’m assuming).

Looking at the behavior of LHS in my graph we see the value 1.136 at 2 (which is the real value of π/2   ?

[image]

Is my approach correct? Is this how I can confirm the expression computationally?

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti Please see updated question.

Comment: 1) If one plots the integrand in WolframAlpha ([link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%28x%5E2%2Bln%28cos+x%29%5E2%29%5E%281%2F8%29+sqrt%281%2F2%2B1%2F2+sqrt%281%2F2%2B1%2F2+sqrt%28ln%28cos+x%29%5E2%2F%28x%5E2%2Bln%28cos+x%29%5E2%29%29%29%29+from+0+to+pi%2F2)), then it seems altogether plausible that the integral (as the area under the curve) is finite. The only possible issue is the singularity near $x=\pi/2$, but it appears to be an integrable singularity. 2) $\frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt[4]{\ln 2}\approx 1.43326$ not $1.307$. WolframAlpha obtains the same via numerical integration.